# Find minimum with conditions

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix with 2 columns and multiple row. I would like to find the index of the minimum value in the first column but only for value for which column 2 smaller than 5 for example.

Here is an example:

```
x = [3,2;2,4;1,6];
```

I would like to the result to be the index 2 because 2 is the min of column one conditioned on the fact column 2 is smaller than 5.

Is there a quicker way to do that in matlab. My current solution is:

```
indicesCandidates = x(:,2) < 5;
minValue = min(x(indicesCandidates,1));
indicesMin = find(x(:,1) == minValue)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can drop the last line by using the second output argument of the [`min`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) function: `[minValue, indicesMin]= min(x(indicesCandidates,1));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And of course the one-liner without changing anything

```
[~,indices] = min(x(x(:,2) < 5,1));
```

The real question is what do you mean by quicker?  If you profile things they are all about the same.

Comment: However, this solution will be very specific to the example, while `indicesCandidates` seems like something that can vary during the run of the code, and only in the OP example it kept fixed.

Comment: @EBH I don't understand your comment at all.  `indicesCandidates` can vary so can the value `5`.  There is nothing sacred about anything in there.  For example `[~, idx] = min(x(x(searchRows,searchCols) < limitValue, finalColumns));` would allow everything to vary and still be one-line...

Comment: The value `5` is not a variable, though.

Answer (score 0):

In continue to what suggested in the comments, you can take only the second ouput of `min`:

```
[~,indicesMin] = min(x(indicesCandidates,1))
```

if you don't really need the `minValue`.